# Converting "dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt" String To DateTime "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000" And Passing It As SQL Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime

I've always struggled with DateTimes and SQL Server.

Even though I've tested the conversion and I've confirmed that it works.

```
string date = "21/12/15 11:45 AM";
DateTime TempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(TempDate);
//Returns 2015.12.21. 11:45:00
```

When I apply the same logic to SQL it displays the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert  to System.Int32.
>   Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

When I use the following code

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@DateNext", SqlDbType.DateTime);
Command.Parameters["@DateNext"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(SurDateNext, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//Where SurDateNext is the following string "21/12/15 11:45 AM"
```

The field I'm trying to insert a value is a DateTime with default formatting of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000`.

Exactly what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you do DateTime tempDate = DateTime.ParseExact(...) then set the parameter Value = tempDate what do you get?

Comment: What is the "type" parameter?

Comment: There's no parameter with a name "type", I'm guessing it appears only in the error message and probably is the SqlDbType.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your stored procedure code?  It looks like the parameter is defined as the wrong type, so SQL is trying to implicitly cast it and can't.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL is expecting a datetime and not an integer value?

Comment: I'm doing everything on c# side without stored procedures. I got it working with the passed string 2015-12-21 11:45:00 so I guess the formating is incorrent. 

The querry that is working:

Update Dates SET DateNow=CAST('2015-12-21 11:45:00' AS DATETIME) WHERE ID='135'

Comment: Inline SQL :(  In any case, then your SQL statement would likely be the culprit.  Are you using a CAST or CONVERT?  I am inferring from the error message that your T-SQL contains a function call, and the parameters for that function call are incorrect.

Comment: Neither.

I'm using Command = new SqlCommand(strSql, Connection) with passed parameters and Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

When I manually execute the query as seen in my last comment, it works.

Comment: Take the `CAST()` out of your SQL code, and don't use string specifiers for your ID. Are you doing some manual string substitution with your parameters further down the road?

Comment: Simply put you need to show us what you are setting the `Command.Text` to.

Comment: string strSql = "INSERT INTO Dates (...,DateNext,...) VALUES (..., @DateNext,...)

using (Command = new SqlCommand(strSql, Connection))
            {
....
Command.Parameters.Add("@DateNext", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                Command.Parameters["@DateNext"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(SurDateNext, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

Comment: Okay, now put that code into your question, but also add the rest of the query. None of this "..." business. That hides things from us that really might turn out to be important. Also include any try/catch blocks... we need to see where the exception is thrown and caught, even if it's in a higher level method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The query that is working:
>   Update Dates SET DateNow=CAST('2015-12-21 11:45:00' AS DATETIME) WHERE ID='135'

The error is complaining about an *integer*, not a date. My guess is you don't see the exception until later in the process, and it's actually complaining about the `ID` value, which seems to contain single quotes where it shouldn't.

You want to structure the code more like this:

```
string sql = "UPDATE [Dates] SET DateNow= @DateNext WHERE ID= @ID ;";
```

If you EVER see raw data value substituted into that query, you're doing it **wrong**!  The whole point of using query parameters is that the parameter *data* is **never** included in the sql command, so that there is no possibility for injecting malicious data into the command.

Additionally, you shouldn't ever be worried about the format of a datetime value going to Sql Server at all. Get you date strings into a .Net DateTime variable, use a parameterized query with a DateTime parameter, and keep your data in a Sql Server DateTime column. Let ADO.Net handle the rest of it.

You seem to believe that Sql Server stores your dates using the `yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000` format, but *this is not accurate*. Sql Server stores dates using a binary (not readable) format. It's just your DB/query tools that show you the other format for convenience.

Let's put the whole thing together:

```
string SurDateNext = "21/12/15 11:45 AM";
string sql = "UPDATE [Dates] SET DateNow= @DateNext WHERE ID= @ID ;";
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateNext", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(SurDateNext, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 135;

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Given a valid connection string and table definition, I promise you that code will work.

If you have **any** additional values that are included in that query and do not use query parameters, let's fix that first. Then make sure the `DateTime.ParseExact()`, `Convert.ToInt32()`, and similar all happen on their own lines, so that you can step through the code and find the exact line that caused the error, along with what the value was.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort and explanation, it will help a lot! And now I finally know what I did wrong.

Comment: And what was that? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to venture an answer on this, because I am fairly certain I know the source of the problem.

The poster indicated that inline SQL (parameterized) was being used.  This would also be applicable to a stored procedure.  The poster also indicated that there is no parameter in his/her SQL named 'type.'  This indicates that the problem is nested within the SQL statement and the error is produced when attempting to call an internal or user-defined SQL function.  Example:

```
UPDATE Employee SET EditedOn = CAST(@SomeDate as datetime)
```

If @SomeDate can't be cast as a valid date time, then the CAST function itself can error.  Here are some observations intended to help solve the problem:

- Use stored procedures if you aren't using some kind of ORM.  It takes only minimal time to learn how to use one, and that tiny upfront investment is paid back about 1,000 times because...
- As you see, inline SQL makes things more difficult to debug.  The first thing I would recommend when encountering any type of SQL error for which the solution isn't readily apparent, is to execute the stored procedure manually through SQL Management Studio, bypassing C#.  This will tell you right away whether the problem is your C# code or your T-SQL.
- Use the correct data types whenever possible.  Don't store dates as nvarchar, or accept a SQL parameter as an nvarchar when it is supposed to be a datetime.  Not only does this make code inherently unsafe and prone to bugs, but, as you start working on larger and larger datasets, performing functions against SQL data can be the difference between an index seek and a table scan, and thus (in a severe case), a stored procedure that executes in milliseconds instead of hours.  If a field is supposed to store a datetime, then make it a datetime.  CAST and CONVERT should be used very sparingly in databases whose schema you own.
- Finally, you can (and should) use SQL profiler to begin a trace against your database.  Then you can see the EXACT query that is being executed.  You can copy/paste the query directly from Profiler into SQL Server Management Studio, play with it until you get it to work, and then fix your C# code.

Comment: I was thinking that way for a while, too, but ultimately "Cannot convert to System.Int32" is a .Net error, rather than a Sql Server error. His problems come before he even opens the DB connection.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Good observation.  I wonder what the value of SurDateNext is in his second code block.

Comment: It's a string. "21/12/15 11:45 AM"

Comment: Can you provide a minimally complete code block that can be executed to replicate your issue?